# Inputs for jedis.incr(byte[] key)

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm currently using Jedis version 2.9.0, and according to the Redis Jedis documentation, the method long jedis.incr(byte[] key) accepts a byte array as its key.
The  thing is, I'm using hash values (MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")) as keys, but I'm not sure about the types/sizes of keys allowed in this command.
I also don't know if this is the 'best practice' in this cases.
Does anyone know how big a byte array can be and still be passed as an argument in this method?

Comment: Please edit the question to include an MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis' key names can be up to 512MB long and are binary-safe. As an MD5 hash is a 128-bit integer, it takes only 16 bytes as a key name and that is well within the limits.

Comment: @Lucas my pleasure - if you find this answer satisfactory, please mark it as such :)